# Threshold to stop generating random unique things

Tags: random, numbers, unique

Given a population size P, I must generate P random, but unique objects. An object is an unordered list of X unique unordered pairs.

I am currently just using a while loop with T attempts at generating a random ordering before giving up. Currently T = some constant.

So my question is at what point should I stop attempting to generate more unique objects i.e. the reasonable value of T.

For example:

1) If I have 3 unique objects and I need just one more, I can attempt up to e.g. 4 times

2) But if I have 999 unique objects and I need just one more, I do not want to make e.g. 1000 attempts

The problem I'm dealing with doesn't absolutely require every unique ordering. The user specifies the number actually, so I want to determine at what point to say that it is not reasonable to generate any more.

I hope that makes sense

If not, a more general case:

Choosing N numbers, at what value of T does it start to get very difficult to start generating more unique random numbers from the possible N.

I'm not sure if T would be the same in both cases but maybe this second case would be sufficient for my needs. I need a relatively large threshold for small values of N and a relatively small threshold for large values of N.

Not that it matters, but this is for a basic genetic algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like lottery tickets/balls selection? For that there is a well-known shuffle algorithm - [Fisher–Yates-Knuth shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Interesting, but I am actually generating random pairs with non repeating numbers i.e I'm picking from 10 unique numbers and placing them into 5 pairs where there is no order. I'm thinking since then maybe I should use probabilities to determine my number i.e. the probability of being able to generate another set of pairs and stop if it falls below a certain threshold. But I don't really know how to determine this

Comment: @ovg It is still a bit unclear how you stop it. Could you provide pseudocode? As of using FYK shuffle, usually one keep objects (pairs in your case) in some structure and just shuffle indices, basically, integer array